# In Eclipse - Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;

Tags: android, eclipse, jar

I can see the same question has been asked many times, but from all the answers available I couldn't find any solution for my problem.

My project is using 2 library projects & I also have included following jar files in libs.

*- android-support-v4.jar*

*- aws-android-sdk-core-2.1.10.jar*

*- aws-android-sdk-s3-2.1.10.jar*

*- crashlytics.jar*

*- gson-2.3.1.jar*

*- library-1.0.15.jar (For Volley)*

*- picasso-2.2.0.jar*

While development, my app was running fine. But the moment I tried to Export, for creating signed APK file I got an error message.

*"Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1"*

In console, I checked the messages,

*"Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
Found 3 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list, but not all the versions are identical."*

In the message itself I checked that one of the android-support-v4.jar (from one of the library projects) files is different, so I replaced it with the other jar file. Now all the jar files are identical.

But now when I try to run the project I am getting one another error message

*"Your project contains error(s), please fix them before running your application."*

Now on checking console I see following messages.

*[2015-07-15 11:23:13 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;*

*[2015-07-15 11:23:13 - MyApp] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;*

From some answers, I found that this issue is because of to multiple occurrences of the same jar file getting added in the project.
All the included jar files are 3rd party & necessary for the project.

I have tried some of the ways suggested in other answer, but I am not able to solve this issue.

Please help me to solve it.

Comment: Please check that v4 library having 3 different versions

Comment: I had checked that & added same version at all places.

Comment: please use one v4 library for all lib projects and main project

Comment: Check your library projects also contains `v4.jar`

Comment: Library projects contain the v4.jar files & I have also added the same v4.jar in all lib & main projects. And after this while running I get Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes; error message.

Comment: delete the other android.v4 support jar.. If still has problems maybe the jars are compiled in a different java version

Comment: What if my library projects also require v4.jar file?

Comment: am asking why multiple v4 libraries.Use one v4 for all

Comment: @RamBabu Okay, but how would I refer that one library to all other projects?

Comment: are you tried with Eclipse project properties->Java build path->Order and export--> Uncheck Android private libraries

Comment: Now I have removed all other v4.jar files except from the main project & also unchecked the Android Private Libraries. Now I am able to run the app but at the time of creating the signed APK  it is showing the Dalvik format error message.

Comment: clean the project and remove bin folder and restart eclipse.now only export as signed apk. dont run

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83323/discussion-between-rambabu-pudari-and-ab1209).

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to solve it.The issue was because of to multiple occurrences of the same set of classes or jar files. In my libs folder, there are 2 jar files

-gson-2.3.1.jar

-aws-android-sdk-core-2.1.10.jar

& both of these contain `Gson` class. In aws it is in package `com.amazonaws.com.google.gson.Gson` & in gson lib it is in `com.google.gson.Gson`.

So because of this I was getting the error message ***Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;***.

Now I have removed the -gson-2.3.1.jar file from libs because it's feature, I can use from the -aws-android-sdk-core-2.1.10.jar lib.

After cleaning the project, I was able to create signed APK file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I've removed Android Private Libraries from Project properties/Java Build Path. The result looks like at the pic

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Solutions to errors conversion of dalvik failure format and error sun / misc / basecoder64 in Eclipse.**

Instructions to solve the problem are:

1. Install Windows XP sp2 with Java 6 or Ubuntu.
2. Download adt version 23.0.2 with SDK 19.
3. Decompress the adt and install it on your computer.
4. Open Eclipse as administrator and import the android file.
5. In the file project.properties add **`target = android-19`**.
6. Export your project and this error will no more appear.